# flat and finite type morphisms

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, flatness

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ a faithfully flat morphism between $k$-schemes. We assume that the fibers  are locally of finite type, do we have that  $f$ is locally of finite type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  Let $Y$ be $\text{Spec} \mathbb{Z}$.  Let $X$ be $\text{Spec} (\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Q})$.

$\textbf{Edit}.$  As pointed out, the OP wants an example over a field.  As the commenters explain, the same idea works over a field $k$ with $Y = \text{Spec} k[t]$ and with $X=\text{Spec}(k[t] \times k(t))$.

Comment: it's not over a field. Sorry, I omit to precise but $k$ is a field.


Comment: Standard dictionary: change $\mathbb{Z}$ to $k[t]$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ to $k(t)$.

Comment: The same trick will work for things over a field.  You can let $Y = \text{Spec }k[x]$ and $X = \text{Spec }(k[x] \oplus k(x) )$.
$$\text{ }$$  
The map $k[x] \to k[x] \oplus k(x)$ is the natural one on each coordinate.  All the fibers are finite type, but the map is not finite type.  It is also clearly flat.